# Double tap/Longpress event on Mapview in android

Tags: android

I have a small map application. I want to set a destination marker on double tap/long press the screen. I also need to get the geometrical position of the tapped point in the map. please help

Comment: Check ths link. It has some samples. It might help you. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VYo2bKIhv4kN0PA4BCqSddwRla5Y6ISPebeL_-eRNlc/edit